# Не работает CardView с RecyclerView в fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть активити, на который накладывается фрагмент. Я пытаюсь добавить CardView с RecyclerView, но выходить

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.hondle.biling/com.example.hondle.biling.activity.MainOnline}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2351)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.hondle.biling.fragments.MainOnlineFragment.onCreateView(MainOnlineFragment.java:85)
    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1789)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:955)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1232)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2324)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2403) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:165) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1373) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Есть делать это в самом активити, то все работает, но во фрагменте нет.
Вот код, на котором спотыкается программа.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_online, container, false);

    List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
    lLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

    RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

    RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(getActivity(), rowListItem);
    rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return view;
}

private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(){

    List<ItemObject> allItems = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("United States", R.drawable.newyork));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Canada", R.drawable.canada));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("United Kingdom", R.drawable.uk));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Germany", R.drawable.germany));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Sweden", R.drawable.sweden));

    return allItems;
}
```

Comment: У вас что-то `null` на 85 строке. Что это за строка?

Comment: Думаю на 84й строке `(RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)`, больше вроде нечему тут null возвращать. Наверное лайаут fragment_main_online не содержит элемента recycler_view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все верно, в этом и была основная проблема, спасибо.

> Думаю на 84й строке
>   (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view), больше вроде
>   нечему тут null возвращать. Наверное лайаут fragment_main_online не
>   содержит элемента recycler_view – xkor 20 часов назад